# Is NCache compatible with .NET Core 3.0?

Tags: .net-core, ncache, .net-core-3.0

I have used NCache tagetting `.net framework 4.6.1` but wanted to convert the same to the `.net core 3.0`. So, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it works with Entity Framework 3.0 as Microsoft have changed a lot of things under-the-hood. I've tried upgrading our .Net Core 2.2 project, but NCache was complaining about quite a few things.